# How to convert Bootstrap rows to columns by Viewport size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a layout that looks like this on `lg` and `sm`:

[image]

I want the same divs to be rows on `lg` and cols on `sm`. Is there a way to do this without having completely different divs? The solution I came up with is:

```
.box-a.row.visible-lg.hidden-sm
.box-b.row.visible-lg.hidden-sm
.box-c.row.visible-lg.hidden-sm

.box-a.col-sm-4.visible-sm.hidden-lg
.box-b.col-sm-4.visible-sm.hidden-lg
.box-c.col-sm-4.visible-sm.hidden-lg
```

But this, like I said, involves redundant code. Is there a way to do this in a cleaner DRYer manner?

Comment: why are you going the reversed way. The normal scenario is to have the cols into rows on smaller devices

Comment: Because I was an idiot. Thanks for pointing this out. Could you add this as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I explained more thoroughly. Hope it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put all columns in a `.row` and, because bootstrap grid is composable, each column can have both `col-sm-4` and `col-lg-12` classes.

The grid structure is:

1. namespace: `col`
2. screenSize: `xs|sm|md|lg`
3. colSpan: `1-12`

So, you are able to have any mix of them:

- When screen is `LG` (to UP) colspan is `12`: `col-lg-12`
- When screen is `SM` (to UP) colspan is `4`: `col-sm-4`

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css";


.box {
  height: 50px;
  background: lightcoral;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-12">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-12">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-12">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

PS: As of bootstrap works, if a DIV has a class `visible-lg` that div will be shown only at `LG` sizes, so, adding a `hidden-sm` class isn't necessary: `.box-a.row.visible-lg.hidden-sm` => `.box-a.row.visible-lg`.

Answer (score 1):

All front-end frameworks like *Bootstrap* use the *grid* system for displaying and positioning content. The grid columns work(is used) in a way that on large screens you show couple of cols in a single row, but as the screen shrinks (table or mobile device), you show fewer (or just one) column in a single row. What you are asking is the quite opposite.

If you still have to use the opposite approach, I suggest you to add a custom class to your cols (cause using the default *col-x-x* is not a good thing and it may affect the rest of your layout), and add some style using the *@media queries* to constraint the width of the columns for various device screens.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by making your small columns full width when they reach a certain break point by using media queries.  If you add a class called full-width  to each column and then add a media query to your css such as:

```
@media (min-width:720px) {
    .full-width {
        width:100%;
        left:0;
    }
}
```

... then this will achieve what you want.  Just modify the `min-width` break point according to the screen size you'd like the columns to become full width at.  [Here's a fiddle showing it at work.](https://jsfiddle.net/a3tgetzj/)

Comment: there is totally unneeded.